# apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style on iPhone 11

Tags: html, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, statusbar, meta

According to the apple developer guidelines for web apps ([found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)), there are 3 choices for the status bar in a web app; default, black and black-translucent.

- Default results in a white status bar with black text
- Black results in a black status bar with white text
- Black-translucent results in a transparent background with white text

I'm trying to implement the **default** behavior, sadly I just end up with a black bar with white text. I have initially opened the app in Safari, then clicked Add to home screen, then this is what I see when opening the resulting "app" on the home screen:

[image]

For reference here is what my HTML looks like:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="mobile-wep-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```

My manifest.json includes this:

```
"display" : "fullscreen"
```

Is this something to do with the iPhone 11? I'm expecting the status bar to have a white background and black text.

Comment: Note: you are inconsistent in your use of the closing slash on the `<meta>` tag but a closing slash is not used or needed in HTML and never has been.

Comment: Thanks, I updated that

Answer (score 4):

After several hours of pulling my hair off on this, I've discovered that dark mode in iOS 13 was to blame.

Going to **Settings > Display & Brightness** and switching back to **Light** mode fixes it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the self-answer, I was going crazy.